# Hartl Rails Tutorial Chapter 7 field with error still black

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-5

In part 7.3.3 all input fields with `class="form_control"` nested in divs with `class="field_with_errors"` [should be colored red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvkmL.png). But [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epr7l.png) what I get.

`custom.scss` includes:

```
#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}
```

As you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epr7l.png) `#error_explanation` works well, `.field_with_errors` does not.
What could be wrong with it?

Link to Heroku: https://daytonaraceway.herokuapp.com/signup

Thanks

Comment: have you defined `.has-error` and `$state-danger-text`.

Comment: `.has-error` is a validation style included into Bootstrap, `$state-danger-text` also predefined within framework, no effect changing var to anything else though

Comment: Do you have the proper includes in your `application.css.scss`

Comment: In rendered HTML code I can see the link to my `custom-self....css` stylesheet located in rails `assets/` folder. Styles seems to be defined correctly

Comment: Here's the link: [https://daytonaraceway.herokuapp.com/signup](https://daytonaraceway.herokuapp.com/signup)

Comment: check your bootstrap configuration or follow the Bootstrap section [5.1.2](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-custom_css) again. I don't think you have configured Bootstrap properly because your text inputs don't look like the default bootstrap text inputs.

Comment: Everithing seems to be OK:
<br/> `Gemfile` includes: `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'`, `gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'`, `gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'`
* `application.js` includes: `//= require jquery`, `//= require bootstrap-sprockets`
* `application.scss` includes: `@import 'custom.scss'`

Comment: Could you also check [the link to the compiled css](https://daytonaraceway.herokuapp.com/assets/application-b8fe56ecdd766c97e69acb95b6bc293b99c1d3d79522af6bfbcffb724c37fc5c.css) please? First few rows indicate Bootstrap presence, last row include style for error field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the code of html template so change of the input field `class: 'form_control'` to `class: 'form-control'` solved the issue